# AWS Tier Limit Alert

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ec2, alert

recently I recive this email with an alert from AWS EC2 instance (its an free tier elegible with T2.Micro). I really do not understand this alert since no content that has been uploaded to the server weighs more than several megabytes. Thanks for your help!

The email alert from AWS:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This alert is about Elastic Block Storage. This means it is related to the sum of provisioned disk capacity multiplied by the running time of your instances/volumes. To get more details how it is calculated, see here: https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/

30GB-Mo under free tier means: You could provision a drive with 30GB and let it run continuously for an entire month.

The warning indicates, that the sum of all provisioned storage of your instances and volumes is higher than 30GB.

Note: The actual data uploaded and/or how much is free, is irrelevant. So for example a micro instance with default settings counts 8GB towards your limit and it does not matter that the fresh Linux without any data is only a couple hundred megabyte.

Answer (score 0):

i asked this in support, this is the answer

> When calculating the charges for EBS volume storage, your charges
>   depend on the size of the volume you've provisioned and the length of
>   time the volume is provisioned in a month.
>
> 1) where that usage comes from? The most important thing to keep in
>   mind is that you are not billed for actual usage-- instead, you're
>   billed for the provisioned size of the volume. For example, if you
>   create a 1 TB volume and only use 1 GB of it in a month, you will be
>   billed for the full 1 TB.
>
> To take another example, if you had a 31 GB volume that was only
>   active for 24 hours in the month of December (a 31 day month,
>   comprised of 744 hours), you'd only be billed for 1 GB-month. If you
>   had a 1 GB volume active for 744 hours in December, you'd be billed
>   the same amount.
>
> 2) how can i see it? If you'd like to look at a more in-depth report
>   of your EBS usage, you can download a usage report here:
>   https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home#/reports
>
> The usage reports can be used to help figure out billing for EBS. Make
>   sure to change the usage value given in the report into GB-months,
>   since the data is presented in byte-hours. You can convert the data
>   into GB-months by dividing the figure presented in byte-hours by
>   1024^3, then divide this figure by the number of hours in the month.
>   You can also find information on EBS charges here
>   https://amzn.to/2BqeGlY
>
> 3) the 30GB EBS free tier is for each EBS instance or is the sum of
>   all the EBS that i could create? The EBS free tier limit is calculated
>   for the total number of volumes provisioned in your account and not
>   per instance. For example, if you simultaneously run a Windows
>   instance and a Linux instance with an attached EBS storage of 30GB
>   volume each, it will intuitively exceed your Free Tier limits, as the
>   total of the volumes would be 60GB.